# Unmapping a "twicely" mapped page in the Linux Kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I use **kmap** to get the first virtual address of a low-memory page, inside a Linux Kernel module.

What happens if I call **kunmap** after that mapping? Is the persistent page mapping totally deleted or just some mapping counter is decreased? (should be 2 before the unmapping)

Comment: why do u want to use kmap for  low-memory page , i require for high memory page.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. By the way, I used it to get the first VA in the page.

Comment: kmap is used to map a highmem page in kernel space (if physical memory > 896 MB ). you can only map 896 mb of physical memory 1:1 mapped that is called low memory.

Comment: you can use kmap for any memory, in case of lowmem it will just return the virtual address of page where as in case of highmap it will map the memory to kernel space and return the virtual address of page

Answer (score 0):

There is no mapping done by kmap if page belongs to low memory and hence there is no action done by kunmap too, but calling them is harmless as these checks are handled in there implementation.

First about kmap

> kmap checks if page is below highmem_start_page(ie lowmemory page) as
>   pages from lowmem are already visible and do not need to be mapped. If
>   the page is already in low memory kmap simply returns the address of it.

Now about kunmap

> kunmap checks if page is below highmem_start_page. If it is, the
>   page already exists in low memory and needs no further handling, hence nop.

Comment: Well, is there an easier way to get the beginning address of a page according to random VA inside it?

Comment: kmap is fine, also you can use : void *page_address(struct page *page);

Comment: Seems better, since we shouldn't call kunmap. Isn't it?

Comment: And, just for clarification - if I used kmap twicely to map a highmem page - does a call to kunmap delete the mapping or just decrease a counter?

Comment: Mappings created with kmap should always be freed with kunmap; a limited number of such mappings is available, so it is better not to hold on to them for too long. kmap calls are additive, so if kmap is called twice on the same page the right thing happens, you shouldn't worry of underlying magic.
And yes the counter alone will decrease by kunmap, this mapping will be deleted once the count is 0.

you can read it in much detail here : 
http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html